# How i convert USD to ETH using json?

Tags: php, json

I used this API but it displays BTC. I want to convert USD to ETH

```
<?php
$url = "https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=2000";
$stats = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
echo "$stats BTC";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this api you cant convert to ETH because this api is only meant to convert a currency to Bitcoin

if you look at the documantation of the api you call
https://www.blockchain.com/api/exchange_rates_api

it says all the way at the bottom that it only converts to BTC so not to ETH

Comment: HI, i want to convert USD to ETH.  Do you know any API and how to do it?

Comment: i dont know how often you want to request this data buhttps://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-currencies seems like a good api

Comment: ok thanks for your valuable response